# Mapping Google App Engine service to Cloudflare

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, cloudflare

I'm having an Google App Engine service residing at https://service-dot-myproject.uc.r.appspot.com/

However I want it to be reachable via https://app.mydomain.com
I have set up the DNS for mydomain.com on Cloudflare and added the custom domain mapping in app engine and set up a dispatch.yaml file

```
- url: "app.mydomain.com/*"
  service: service
```

Is there a way to somehow map

`https://service-dot-myproject.uc.r.appspot.com -> https://app.mydomain.com` ?

currently https://app.mydomain.com only resolves to defaultservice

Comment: See Google's documentation [Mapping Custom Domains](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/mapping-custom-domains)

Comment: I did this, but now app.mydomain.com points to the default service. I tried to create a dispatch.yaml file - url: "app.mydomain.com/*"
  service: service it still goes to default service

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following dispatch.yaml file resolved the issue

```
dispatch:
  - url: "app.mydomain.com/*"
    service: service
```

Also the file must be separatly deployed via:

```
gcloud app deploy dispatch.yaml
```